# How to measure the amount of memory webview consumes?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

Would there be a way to programmatically measure and monitor the memory consumed by

```
WebView.loadUrl
```

when we open a webview activity in our Android app?

I have noticed that for some reason the webpage that I open using `WebView.loadUrl` has some memory leak and the amount of memory it uses keeps on increasing under random conditions. I wanted to programatically catch that and run some method if the memory usage of my `WebView` page goes beyond a certain range.

Answer (score 3):

Finding a specific method memory usage is sort if not so possible but there is a small trick to get a probable estimate:

1. Run the following code and save it somewhere
2. Run the webview.loadurl("...")
3. Rerun the following code and subtract the new memory usage from previous to get an idea of how much memory the webview.loadUrl max use at maximum

   `final Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
   final long usedMemInMB=(runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()) / 1048576L;
   final long maxHeapSizeInMB=runtime.maxMemory() / 1048576L;
   final long availHeapSizeInMB = maxHeapSizeInMB - usedMemInMB;`

Answer (score -2):

You can use the memory profile tool from Android Studio. It shows all the memory usage.

[Memory Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m8zY.png)

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler

Comment: The asker is looking for a programmatic way to respond to large memory usage, not a way to profile it in their development environment.

Comment: "WebView.loadUrl has some memory leak and the amount of memory it uses keeps on increasing under random condition. ".  How you detect memory leaks? It could be Leak Canary or Memory Profiler tool.

Comment: "I wanted to programmatically catch that and run some method if the memory usage of my webview page goes beyond certain range."

Comment: For one problem there are a lot of solutions my friend :). I only want to help from my point of view.